# Query regarding a use case in java multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a use case in java multi threading and i need to know whether i need to synchronize the list data-structure for this case. Also trying to achieve the case without the synchronization.

Use Case :

I am trying to collect some stats for which i might need to increment some set of values. For this i am pre-loading a arraylist with 8 elements and all initialized to 0. As and when requests arrives, each request will increment(update) any one element(using index) based on the data in the request. Thus the stats will be getting collected in this arraylist. This is the only thread which is gonna access this list to write in it in sequence. In any case there won't be parallel writes to the elements in this list.

I will be having a reader thread which might try to get all data from this arraylist for say every 2 mins. Will be constructing a for loop to the size of the list and get the elements by its index. Its even ok for me to get little old data from the list.

Questions :

1. I need to know on whether this arraylist needs to be synchronized for the above usage pattern ??
2. If it not required to be sychronized, operating both threads in parallel should not throw any kind of exception, though getting little stale data in reader thread is fine.
3. If it needs to be synchronized, it will be a performance hit for me since this list is only for collecting stats and i can't overload it with synchronization. Any other solution without synchronization for this case.. ?

Comment: You talk about an ArrayList, but not about a data model.  It is a better practice to speak of thread safefy policies for *objects* (whose mutable state you wish to protect during concurrent access) than to speak of accessing a data structure in a safe way (for example, how is the data structure implemented?).  If you've not already, I suggest you reason on your problem domain carefully and create a corresponding data model as the first step.  With that done, you can more cogently reason about the state transitions for your objects and, then, how to protect them.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two threads that would be accessing the ArrayList, so there is a need of synchronization.
Synchronization is not about just writing, it is also about reading, so that stale values are not read by the Reader thread.

As suggested by @OldCurmudgeon, you can have an ArrayList of AtomicLong values.
The *incrementAndGet()* method in AtomicLong makes the incrementing atomic so no stale values are read.

To your questions

> > 1. I need to know on whether this arraylist needs to be synchronized for the >>above usage pattern ??

The ArrayList need to be synchronized for both get and set.
You can use 
`List<AtomicLong> stats = new ArrayList<AtomicLong>();
 stats = Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)`

> > 2. If it not required to be sychronized, operating both threads in parallel >>should not throw any kind of exception, though getting little stale data in >>reader thread is fine.

The unsynchronized code would also work. The only time it might throw an error is when you try to add an element to ArrayList and in the meanwhile the ReaderThread is reading the data from ArrayList using Iterator.

> > 3. If it needs to be synchronized, it will be a performance hit for me since >>this list is only for collecting stats and i can't overload it with >>synchronization. Any other solution without synchronization for this case.. ?

Create Synchronized-List of AtomicLong. 
Read from the List using "get" operation.
Write to the thread using incrementAndGet() method.

Comment: "The only time it might throw an error is when you try to add an element to ArrayList and in the meanwhile the ReaderThread is reading the data from ArrayList using Iterator."  

I won't be adding new elements to the list, i will just be setting(updating) value to one or more elements using index position. Also the reader thread will use for loop(instead of iterator) to fetch the elements from the arraylist using index position. Do i still need to synchronize or use atomic long instead of just long ??

Comment: The very point of synchronization is to help every thread read the latest values instead of viewing the old values from caches, registers etc.  By using Synchronized-List the AtomicLong, the operation of "incrementing" --> which is a combination of "get value from List" + "incrementing value" becomes a single atomic operation. As long as there is no structural modification to the List, the Iterator would work fine. Since you are using for-loop,  even that should work too without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one "writing thread", as you have stated, then there is no need to synchronize to keep the integrity of the data. You have stated that reading stale data is acceptable, so that is not an issue.

What remains is whether updating an individual value is an atomic operation, meaning that you cannot read a partially updated value. You said that you are incrementing counters, so I presume these are ints or Integers, either way, those increments should be atomic, so you should not require synchronization.

Rereading your question, you refer only to "elements", which I assumed to be an int or an Integer. If, instead, they are complex data - multiple values that have to be updated, such as if you were counting attempted transactions and also successful and failed transactions - then you might want to synchronize those to be sure they all "add up".

Comment: Thank you Jim.

The elements in the arraylist will be Long values. Initialized to 0(zero) in the starting and then incremented. There won't be any complex data inside the arraylist. And only one element of the arraylist will be incremented at a time.

Comment: There is a need to synchronize because one thread writes and another thread reads. If you want the reader to see everything the writer writes, you need some sort of synchronization. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @LewBloch No, in my case its not necessarily the reader need to see all the latest data that the writer writes. Its ok for the reader thread to see some stale data but the only thing should not happen is there should be any sort of error / exception in both reader / writer thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you will be having a very heavy list, after all the atomic overhead will enforce synchronization n times. Why don't you change the list to a concurrent one?

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage without an ArrayList, then you can try an AtomicLongArray of size 8.

```
On construction, all elements will be initialized to 0.

To write you can invoke incrementAndGet(index)

To get a value from an index, you will do  get (index)
```

This will give you the performance of an array and thread safety of Java atomics. No external synchronization required.

Answer (score -1):

As @Jim pointed out - in your scenario you don't need to worry as there is only one writer.

Even if there are more than one writer you still don't need to synchronsie if you use `Atomic...` for your values.

Here's a demo using `AtomicInteger`:

```
// Use AtomicInteger to ensure no stats are missed.
final AtomicInteger[] stats = new AtomicInteger[10];
final Random random = new Random();
volatile boolean stop = false;

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // Start them all at zero.
    Arrays.setAll(stats, i -> new AtomicInteger());
    // Fire up some threads.
    Thread writer = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            // Increment a random stat.
            stats[random.nextInt(stats.length)].incrementAndGet();
            // Give a little time.
            sleep(10);
        }
    });

    // Start my reader.
    Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
        while (!stop) {
            // Add up all of the values.
            int total = Arrays.stream(stats)
                    .mapToInt(a -> a.get())
                    .sum();
            System.out.println("Sum = " + total);
            sleep(20);
        }
    });
    reader.start();
    // Start my writer.
    writer.start();
    // Wait for the writer to finish.
    writer.join();
    // stop the reader.
    stop = true;
    reader.join();
}

private void sleep(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a need for synchronization because more than one thread accesses the data. This answer is incorrect, and it contradicts itself because its example uses synchronization, via the `AtomicInteger` type.

Comment: @LewBloch - Just because more than one thread accesses the data does NOT mean it needs synchronizing. If there is only one thread writing, the data structure does not need to morph and old data is not a problem (as it is in this case) there is no need for any exclusive access so no synchronization is required.

Comment: Just because more than one thread accesses the data DOES mean it needs synchronization. If a thread writes to shared data that has no synchronization mechanism (`volatile`, `synchronized`, `java.util.concurrent` structures, etc.), then your reader threads very well might see none of the writes. I strongly suggest that you read _Java Concurrency in Practice_, by Brian Goetz, et al., or really any detailed information about Java concurrency.

Comment: @LewBloch Using AtomicLongArray could work out without explicit synchronization ??

Comment: Perhaps. But using `AtomicLongArray` is using explicit synchronization, in my book. The use of a synchronized type is explicit, yes?

Comment: @LewBloch - I finally worked out why we disagree. To me `synchronization` means using either `synchronized` or `Lock.lock()`. It appears you also include using `volatile` and atomics.

Comment: Synchronization is synchronization no matter how you accomplish it.